# Logstash '_grokparsefailure' issue

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, grok

I am using custom grok pattern to parse my log file, Not matter what i do it always give me the *_grokparsefailure* exception.

However, it work perfectly on https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

My custom pattern file is located at,

> C:\Users\Username\projects\Logstash\bin\patterns
>
> Filename: mylogpattern

```
    LogLevel [I|V|D|M|W|E|A|F]
    MODULE \b\w+\b|------
    MESSAGEID (?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+))|----
    SUBMODULE (.*?:)
    MESSAGE (.*)|(.*?:)|(.*\s*?:)
```

My Logstash Config File Looks like this:

```
input{
    beats{
      host => "192.168.56.1"
      port => 7088
      congestion_threshold => 200
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "MyLog"{
        grok{
          patterns_dir => ["C:\Users\Username\projects\Logstash\logstash\bin\patterns"]
          match => { "message" => "%{YEAR:Year}%{MONTHNUM:Month}%{MONTHDAY:Day} %{HOUR:Hour}%{MINUTE:Minute}%{SECOND:Second} %{LogLevel:LogVerbosity} %{MODULE:MODULENAME}%{SPACE}%{MESSAGEID:MESSAGEID} %{SUBMODULE:SUBMODULE} %{MESSAGE:MESSAGE}" }
          add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
          add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
        }
    }  
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
      manage_template => false
      index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
}
```

Sample Log File:

> 20160509 115108 I GEN    0000 ConnectionHandler.reconnect: Reconnect
>   to the DB was done.
>
> 20160509 115108 I GEN    0000 84.1.3.1000012 : Reconnect to the DB was
>   done.

It works perfectly on grok debugger, but somehow it is failing while parsing.

```
tags:beats_input_codec_plain_applied, _grokparsefailure
```

Could someone please help me out with this, What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1 :**

I can see, for first few seconds, Logs are getting parsed. But , After that it is throwing the error.

All log follows essentially the same format, also i have added GREEDYDATA filter for the long messages, it is able to parse it successfully. I can still see some parsed logs in kibana.

Its just the log count is really high and log file also have continuous blank lines in between.

Does it try to parse those blank lines as well ?

Comment: Note that the path you mention `C:\Users\Username\projects\Logstash\bin\patterns` is different than the one you have in your config `C:\Users\Username\projects\Logstash\logstash\bin\patterns`. Is that just a copy/paste error?

Comment: yes, it may be trying to parse those blank lines

Answer (score 1):

i think there is a mistake at your grok paterns_dir

try this one : `patterns_dir => "./patterns"`